# Importing Subversion repository which is well formed now, but was not well formed before

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, hgsubversion, repository-design

I would like to import the source code from [a Subversion repository to Mercurial](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=161807). Using [Hg Subversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) I imported it. The problem is, the layout of the SVN repo is the default one - with `trunk` directory, branches at the `branches` directory etc. - today, but it was not so before. Some time ago, all directories of the project were a the root repository, so Hg Subversion could not convert the `branches` directory to Mercurial branches and the new Mercurial repository just contains the directories `branches` and `trunk`.

I converted the branches directories into Mercurial branches the "hard way":

- for each branch `b`
- `hg mv branches/$b .`
- `hg rm branches trunk`
- `hg branch $b`
- `hg commint -m "Creating branch $b"`

However, I wonder: is there a better way to do it? How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, there was no better method. This situation was very specific, and there was an workaround, so I assume a "fix" wouldn't probably be worth it. I solved following the steps in the question, and would recommend it for most people in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

hgsubversion should have auto-detected the presence of the trunk/tags/branches directories and done the intelligent thing. Did you force hgsubversion into a non-automatic mode to get it to not do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ hg help convert

The filemap is a file that allows filtering and remapping of files and
directories. Each line can contain one of the following directives:

  include path/to/file-or-dir

  exclude path/to/file-or-dir

  rename path/to/source path/to/destination  <== YOUR CASE

--filemap FILE     remap file names using contents of file
```